# Grounded phase conductors

Tags: ac

I'm learning about grounding and I'm having trouble grasping the theory behind a grounded phase conductor, for example a corner grounded delta system has a grounded phase. My mind is saying
 "no the phase can't be grounded" 
wouldn't that create a ground fault? I think this concept might break free some older stuck ideas about what grounding is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well it is true... in an isolated system, any single point can be connected to ground! In fact you can have several "isolated" systems with all kinds of ground references. A Delta is an odd case, because as you've observed, there is no way to make a true "balanced" ground that could serve as a low impedance return path. I recall having the same odd feelings about an "open delta" transformer, and being surprised you could get away with such a thing. :-)

Comment: The advantage is only 3 conductors are needed, no separate additional Ground conductor.... usually used for motors as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

**As long as the circuit has no other path to ground** you can connect any point in a circuit to "ground".

What you are really doing is making that point in the circuit a fixed reference point. All voltages in that circuit can then be referenced from that grounding point.

It's like having three mountains. If you stand way down here at sea level, you see three heights of the mountains, all plus relative to you.

However, if you stand on top of the first mountain, the tops of the other two mountains are now at a different height with respect to your viewpoint. One may be plus, one may be minus etc. Looking back to where you started from, that is now a big negative height value to you.

Voltage is just a potential, just like height is.

You just can't stand in two places at the same time.

You also can't connect two different ground points together. Just like you can argue all day with your buddy who is still down at sea level about how high the mountains are.

Just as the mountains did not change when you climbed one, the circuit does not change either. The currents within the circuit behave exactly as they did before you grounded that corner. They simply look different from your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the mountain analogy.  Sometimes smelting  plants use ungrounded systems.  So could they potentially use the corner grounded delta system but not ground the B phase? Then all legs would be hot and there wouldn't be a neutral. I had a question about high leg delta systems. It looks like two of the phases share a common ground that is connected midway in both of the separate windings in the transformer. This also seems like it would be a ground fault because two phases would be grounded on the same system. Unless I'm wrong and they aren't commonly grounded.

Comment: @EricHeagan, you would have to show a picture of that.

Comment: Here is a diagram that I found.   https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2Fe%2Fea%2FCenterTappedTransformer.svg%2F250px-CenterTappedTransformer.svg.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHigh-leg_delta&docid=dz-pcM4ky8barM&tbnid=-oz1pFLAzPKQGM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi26InRofjSAhWFh1QKHS3fDLMQMwgbKAAwAA..i&w=250&h=258&client=tablet-android-verizon&bih=1024&biw=768&q=high%20leg%20delta%20transformer&ved=0ahUKEwi26InRofjSAhWFh1QKHS3fDLMQMwgbKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: @EricHeagan Oh.. I see what  you are asking.. Yes you can ground different points on either side of a transformer, as long as there is not other connection between them. Remember, they are two entirely different circuits, that just happen to be magnetically coupled together (not electrically coupled.)

Comment: In this diagram there are three windings. Am I understanding that there are two windings that are bonded together at their midpoint,  and this is then bonded to the grounding bus? Isn't that electrically coupled? I can't find a good photograph of the part I'm looking for.

Comment: @EricHeagan, I mean other than ground.